# Nearest-neighbor interpolation in canvas (internet explorer 9)

Tags: javascript, canvas, d3.js, internet-explorer-9, nearest-neighbor

i've created a simple image viewer (with grid and image) with an canvas (the image only) and some svg-gridlines thanks to d3.js (simliar to [this](http://bl.ocks.org/tommct/8116740)). I use the zoom-function from d3.js to zoom and pan my image/gridlines.

My image on the canvas should use the Nearest-neighbor interpolation. I've set many style elements to achieve this goal. Chrome and Firefox works well, but i have problems with the Internet Explorer 9 (i need to support ie9). In IE9 the image is always blurred.

**Does the internet explorer 9 repect the Nearest-neighbor interpolation for the canvas?**

Are my settings correct?

My canvas code in d3.js:

```
canvas
        .attr("width", dx)
        .attr("height", dy)
        .attr("style", "outline: thin solid black;")
        .style("width", width + "px")
        .style("height", height + "px")
        .style("transform", "translate(" + marginleft + "px,0)")
        .style("image-rendering","-moz-crisp-edges")
        .style("image-rendering","-o-crisp-edges")
        .style("image-rendering","-webkit-optimize-contrast")
        .style("image-rendering","optimize-contrast")
        .style("image-rendering","pixelated")
        .style("-ms-interpolation-mode","nearest-neighbor")
        .call(drawImage);
```

this d3.js code should represent (mostly) this css

```
   img { 
            image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;             
            image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;          // Firefox
            image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges;            // Opera
            image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast; // Chrome (and eventually Safari)
            image-rendering: pixelated;                 // Chrome
            image-rendering: optimize-contrast;         // CSS3 Proposed
            -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;   // IE8+
        }
```

this is my draw function

```
function drawImage(canvas2: any) {
        var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");
        var image = context.createImageData(dx, dy);

        for (var y = 0, p = -1; y < dy; ++y) {
            for (var x = 0; x < dx; ++x) {
                let pixval = heatmap[y][x];                                     
                var c = d3.rgb(color(pixval));
                if(pixval <= min){
                    c = d3.rgb(255,255,255);    
                }
                image.data[++p] = c.r;
                image.data[++p] = c.g;
                image.data[++p] = c.b;
                image.data[++p] = 255;
            }
        }

        context.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
        context.ImageSmoothingEnabled = false; //context.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
        context.msImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
        context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

        context.putImageData(image, 0, 0);
        imageObj.src = canvas.node().toDataURL();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the notes on compatibility on [MDN's image-rendering page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering)
 (emphasis mine)

> [1] **Internet Explorer 7 and 8** supports the non-standard -ms-interpolation-mode property with two values (bicubic and nearest-neighbor):
>
> applies only to images (JPG, GIF, PNG, ...)
>
> in IE7 only for images without transparency
>
> does not inherit
>
> default value IE7: nearest-neighbor (low quality)
>
> default value IE8: bicubic (high quality)
>
> **obsolete as of IE9**

So looks like the answer is no, IE9 doesn't support it.

Comment: thanks for your answer. That sounds bad. Do you know any "emulation"-library for that?

Comment: I don't know. Why do you need this feature so much? Surely there's a reason it's marked obsolete, but I'm not familiar enough with this topic to tell.